# Scope of Objects Passed as Arguments - Python

Tags: python, object, sqlalchemy, pyqt4

I want to send a session object of sqlalchemy to a function of another class .

From class **OraDialog**'s function ***oraconnect*** to class **oraconn**'s ***assign*** function .

Actually My need is to use the session object in **oraconn**'s another function ***map***

I can't send the session object directly to ***map*** function because it is a slot - it is triggered before .
I intended to define the assign function primarily to get the session object.

The Error : ( including print statements )

`<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x030808F0>`
`<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x030808F0>`
`This is in assign`
`None`
`This is in map`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "C:\Users\Arul\Desktop\dbvis\oraconn.py", line 44, in map`
`for t in self.s.query(tables):`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'query'`

The oraconn class's assign and map functions :

```
def assign(self,s):
    self.s=s
    print self.s
    print "This is in assign"
def map(self):
    print self.s
    print "This is in map"
    self.table_no=0
    for t in self.s.query(tables):
        self.table_no=self.table_no+1
        table_list.append(t.table_name)
    self.item=QtCore.QStringList()
    for c in self.s.query(columns):
        self.item.append(c.column_name)
    self.ui.list_col.addItems(self.item)
```

SO ,
The assign function receives the object properly . But the map function can't use it - It says Nonetype

My Question :
Two functions of same class can't use an object ?

I must have done something silly - so plz point out......

( I'm using windows7 / python 2.6 / PyQt4 /sqlalchemy /cx_oracle)

**Edit :**
The calling class :

```
class OraDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
def __init__(self,parent=None):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
    self.odia=Ui_Dialog()
    self.odia.setupUi(self)
    self.uiobj=oraconn()
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.odia.but_con,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.uiobj.oraconnect)
def oraconnect(self):
    self.setVisible(0)
    eng_str="oracle://"+self.odia.line_user.text()+":"+self.odia.line_pass.text()+"@localhost:1521/"+self.odia.line_sid.text()+"?mode="+self.odia.line_role.text()
    engine_str=str(eng_str)
    engine=create_engine(engine_str)
    Session=sessionmaker(engine)
    self.s=Session()
    print self.s
```

**Problem Solved :**
The problem is - i've created two instances and passed from one to another .

Corrected code :

```
oraconn.assign(myapp,self.s)
```

where
oraconn -> class
assign  -> function of oraconn
myapp   -> instance of oraconn , declared for main application
self.s  -> the argument i wanted to pass

Thank you Kirk ....

Comment: Show the code that's leading to this. How are the `assign` and `map` methods called?

Comment: Your first code snippet is labeled "The OraDialog class's oraconnect function :". I can't tell what you mean there. Are those both methods in a class called OraDialog?

Comment: @Kirk Strauser ,oops, sorry , my mistake ... i've edited now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Qt, then this is likely a GUI app. Maybe there are threading issues; maybe `self` refers to different objects. It's hard to tell with only what you've given us. Before you go any further, add:

```
print self
```

near the top of each method. At least then you can confirm whether both are operating on the same object.

---

In OraDialog.**init**, you're saying `self.uiobj=oraconn()`. Is that the object that's giving you problems? If so: notice that you're creating at as an instance variable, so that each OraDialog object has a different .uiobj object. Could you try making that a class variable by writing:

```
class OraDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    uiobj = oraconn()
    def __init__() [...]
```

instead? That is, define `uiobj` as belonging to all instances of the class, not just one instance.

Comment: ya , i want to pop-up a dialog to get some username,password and then use them in QMainWindow...

Comment: i printed self at both functions - Got two diff addresses . It seems u're correct - threading issues . The values are :                                                <__main__.oraconn object at 0x02ED7660>
this is in assign
<__main__.oraconn object at 0x02DC4F18>                          this is in map

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted seems to be okay, I can't spot any obvious mistakes.

The problem must be on the calling side. As the self reference can be passed explicitly to methods (via `OraDialog.map(my_object)`, where `my_object` could be anything) this perfectly possible. Also note that this has nothing to do with scoping.

You should check calling code of the `map` function. It is very likely it is called on a different object as `assign`.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't call methods like that. It kills polymorphism, **the** foundation of duck typing.

Comment: I didn't say you should do that, but it is possible and it even may the reason of the problem in question. That's why I have mentioned it.